# useEffect hook infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to react. here is my problem

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useJwt } from "react-jwt";
import { get_single_user_url } from "../../store/api";
import UrlCard from "../UrlCard/UrlCard";
import "./Urls.css";

function Urls() {
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);
  const { decodedToken } = useJwt(localStorage.token);
  const userId = decodedToken !== null ? decodedToken.userId : "";

  useEffect(() => {
    const hit = async (userId) => {
      get_single_user_url(userId).then((data) => setUrls(data));
      const data = await get_single_user_url(userId);
      setUrls(data);
      console.log(data);
    };
    hit(userId);
  }, []);

  return <div className="urls"></div>;
}

export default Urls;
```

so this useeffect will call a function

> get_single_user_data(userId)

and it should return an array of urls from the database. But it returned this

> {kind: "ObjectId",
> path: "user",
> reason: {},
> stringValue: """",
> value: "",
> **proto**: Object}

This is the function

```
export const get_single_user_url = async (userId) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://192.168.43.62:5000/getUrls",
      data: { user: userId },
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}` },
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

here userId is passed through the body. Now in the backend when I print the value of **req.body**, it gives **user** property with an empty string.

> { user: "" }

I have tried it without using useEffect but then it goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an empty dependency array on your `useEffect`, it will only fire once. It looks like the `userId` is an empty string when running.

You'll want to add some logic in your `hit` function to only make the request if `userId` is not empty. Additionally, to get your effect to run when needed, you should add `userId` to the dependency array (`[userId]`).

If `userId` isn't needed anywhere other than this function, you might use the token instead, and parse the `userId` in your `hit` function.

```
const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);
const { decodedToken } = useJwt(localStorage.token);

useEffect(() => {
  const hit = async (decodedToken) => {
    const userId = decodedToken !== null ? decodedToken.userId : "";
    if (!userId) {
      return;
    }
    
    get_single_user_url(userId).then((data) => setUrls(data));
    const data = await get_single_user_url(userId);
    setUrls(data);
    console.log(data);
  };

  hit(decodedToken);
}, [decodedToken]);
```